# How to control the margin size around subplots?

Tags: matlab, plot, subplot

I'm plotting 5 x 3 plots using subplot command, but there are massive margins around each subplot.

How do I control the margin size around them?

```
figure;
for c=1:15
    subplot(5,3,c); 
    imagesc(reshape(image(:,c), 360,480)); 
    colormap gray; 
    axis image;
end
```

[image]

Comment: Have a look here - http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2012/12/21/figure-margins-subplot-spacings-and-more/.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that Matlab assigns the `position` property of each axis such that there is space around each plot. You can either adjust the `position` property, or you can get [subaxis](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3696-subaxis-subplot) from the File Exchange and set up the subplots the way you like.

Comment: +1 here is a link to a MathWorks solution stating the same advice: http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1XTXW0/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-1XTXW0

Answer (score 11):

Take a look at the axes's **LooseInset** and **OuterPosition** properties: 
http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/axes-looseinset-property/

Answer (score 3):

Since MATLAB R2019b you can use [tiledlayout](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tiledlayout.html) function to control the spacing of the subplots.

---

Here's an example which shows how to obtain subplots without tile spacing:

```
figure
example_image = imread('cameraman.tif');
t = tiledlayout(5,3);
nexttile

for c= 1:15
    imagesc(example_image(:,c))
    if c < 15
        nexttile
    end
end

t.TileSpacing = 'None';
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, you could try Chad Greene's [smplot](https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/52978-smplot-for-small-multiples) from the FileExchange. This will produce a ['small multiple'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_multiple) plot and automatically deal with some of the hassle of Matlab's `position` property.

Example below showing default `subplot` behaviour, `smplot` with axis off and `smplot` with axis on, respectively:

```
image = randn(360*480,15);

% default subplot
figure;
for c=1:15
    subplot(5,3,c); 
    imagesc(reshape(image(:,c), 360,480)); 
    colormap gray; 
    axis image;
end
```

[image: default matlab subplot]

```
% smplot axis off
figure;
for c=1:15
    smplot(5,3,c);
    imagesc(reshape(image(:,c), 360,480)); 
    colormap gray; 
    axis off;
end
```

[image: smplot with axis off]

```
% smplot axis on
figure;
for c=1:15
    smplot(5,3,c,'axis','on');
    imagesc(reshape(image(:,c), 360,480)); 
    colormap gray; 
    axis tight;
end
```

[image: smplot with axis on]

Answer (score 0):

To minimize the white space surrounding each subplot, run: [1]

```
for c=1:15
  h_ax = subplot(5,3,c);
  % [...]

  outerpos = get(h_ax,'OuterPosition');
  ti = get(h_ax,'TightInset');
  left = outerpos(1) + ti(1);
  bottom = outerpos(2) + ti(2);
  ax_width = outerpos(3) - ti(1) - ti(3);
  ax_height = outerpos(4) - ti(2) - ti(4);
  set(h_ax,'Position',[left bottom ax_width ax_height]);
end
```

This implementation automates the principle outlined in Jonas's answer.

[1] https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2015b/matlab/creating_plots/save-figure-with-minimal-white-space.html