# Removing deadspace in subplots while retaining title & labels

Tags: image, matlab, plot, subplot

Hi I have a problem in matlab 
I want to create a figure containing 10 subplots. in 2X5 orientation. But the problem is that I want to reduce the deadspace area between them. I also require to keep the title, xlabel for the first row of images & the xlabel(only) for the second row of images. No ylabels are required.

Till now I have done this code (for the first row): Once I figure the first row , the second row should be a piece of cake.

```
close all

figure,set(gca,'Color','none')
subplot(2,5,1);subplot('Position',[0.02 0.51  0.18 0.45]);get(gca,'position');set(gca, 'XTick', []);set(gca, 'YTick', []);
imshow(I);hold on; axis off;
contour((BW(:,:,1)), [0 0], 'r','LineWidth',2);
hold off;title('1st curve','FontSize',12);xlabel('(a)','FontSize',12)
subplot(2,5,2);subplot('Position',[0.215 0.51  0.18 0.45]);get(gca,'position');set(gca, 'XTick', []);set(gca, 'YTick', []);
imshow(I);hold on; axis off;
contour((BW(:,:,2)), [0 0], 'r','LineWidth',2);
hold off;title('2nd curve','FontSize',12);xlabel('(b)','FontSize',12)
subplot(2,5,3);subplot('Position',[0.410 0.51  0.18 0.45]);get(gca,'position');set(gca, 'XTick', []);set(gca, 'YTick', []);
imshow(I);hold on; axis off;
contour((BW(:,:,3)), [0 0], 'r','LineWidth',2);
hold off;title('3rd curve','FontSize',12);xlabel('(c)','FontSize',12)
subplot(2,5,4);subplot('Position',[0.605 0.51  0.18 0.45]);get(gca,'position');set(gca, 'XTick', []);set(gca, 'YTick', []);
imshow(I);hold on; axis off;
contour((BW(:,:,4)), [0 0], 'r','LineWidth',2);
hold off;title('4th curve','FontSize',12);xlabel('(d)','FontSize',12)
subplot(2,5,5);subplot('Position',[0.8 0.51  0.18 0.45]);get(gca,'position');set(gca, 'XTick', []);set(gca, 'YTick', []);
imshow(I);hold on; axis off;
contour((BW(:,:,5)), [0 0], 'r','LineWidth',2);
hold off;title('5th curve','FontSize',12);xlabel('(e)','FontSize',12)
```

This gives me an output like this :

[image]

As you can see the fourth image is not present. What is wrong with the code ? I have rechecked my code several times and the computations too but could not find any error.

Interestingly when I run this code [only having the 4th subplot]

```
subplot(2,5,4);subplot('Position',[0.605 0.51  0.18 0.45]);get(gca,'position');set(gca, 'XTick', []);set(gca, 'YTick', []);
imshow(I);hold on; axis off;
contour((BW(:,:,4)), [0 0], 'r','LineWidth',2);
hold off;title('4th curve','FontSize',12);xlabel('(d)','FontSize',12)
```

I get this answer !! 
[image]

Please can anyone tell me where am I wrong ? Note I do require the xlabel and the title for the first row of the images.

EDIT: I then went and did this thing. Now I get the five images. However the spacing between the images in all the cases are not uniform, specifically spacing between 1st & 2nd image is different from the rest.

My code :

```
close all

figure,set(gca,'Color','none')
subplot(2,5,1);subplot('Position',[0.02 0.51  0.18 0.45]);get(gca,'position');set(gca, 'XTick', []);set(gca, 'YTick', []);
imshow(I);hold on; axis off;
contour((BW(:,:,1)), [0 0], 'r','LineWidth',2);
hold off;title('1st curve','FontSize',12);xlabel('(a)','FontSize',12)
subplot(2,5,2);subplot('Position',[0.210 0.51  0.18 0.45]);get(gca,'position');set(gca, 'XTick', []);set(gca, 'YTick', []);
imshow(I);hold on; axis off;
contour((BW(:,:,2)), [0 0], 'r','LineWidth',2);
hold off;title('2nd curve','FontSize',12);xlabel('(b)','FontSize',12)
subplot(2,5,3);subplot('Position',[0.405 0.51  0.18 0.45]);get(gca,'position');set(gca, 'XTick', []);set(gca, 'YTick', []);
imshow(I);hold on; axis off;
contour((BW(:,:,3)), [0 0], 'r','LineWidth',2);
hold off;title('3rd curve','FontSize',12);xlabel('(c)','FontSize',12)
subplot(2,5,4);subplot('Position',[0.600 0.51  0.18 0.45]);get(gca,'position');set(gca, 'XTick', []);set(gca, 'YTick', []);
imshow(I);hold on; axis off;
contour((BW(:,:,4)), [0 0], 'r','LineWidth',2);
hold off;title('4th curve','FontSize',12);xlabel('(d)','FontSize',12)
subplot(2,5,5);subplot('Position',[0.795 0.51  0.18 0.45]);get(gca,'position');set(gca, 'XTick', []);set(gca, 'YTick', []);
imshow(I);hold on; axis off;
contour((BW(:,:,5)), [0 0], 'r','LineWidth',2);
hold off;title('5th curve','FontSize',12);xlabel('(e)','FontSize',12)
```

Now I get this answer : 
[image]

How can I correct this? Pleae help! Thanks in advance!!

EDIT : I seems to have solved this problem. Please seem my answer below. However I do have query.
I wanted to make the code run in loops and so implemented this code .

```
I = imread('coins.png');
I = imresize(I,[128 128]);
for no = 1:5
    subplot('Position',[0.025+0.19*(no-1) 0.51 0.19 0.48]);
    imshow(I);
    get(gca,'Position');set(gca, 'XTick', []);set(gca, 'YTick', []);
    title({'Image' num2str(no)});
    subplot('Position',[0.025+0.19*(no-1) 0.03  0.19 0.48]);
     imshow(I);
    get(gca,'Position');set(gca, 'XTick', []);set(gca, 'YTick', []);
    title({'Image' num2str(no)});
end
```

The answer comes out as this 
[image]

Can this code be vectorised ??

Comment: You don't have to call `subplot` twice. It creates a second subplot. The help says that _subplot('Position',positionVector) creates a new axes at the position specified by positionVector_. If you want to distribute the images along the xaxis, you can use `linspace(0.02,0.8,5)` that will create a vector of equally spaced values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MATLAB subplot margin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410873/matlab-subplot-margin)

Answer (score 3):

The built in `subplot` function is really powerful and nice. Instead of going with custom computed positions, I think it is best to stick with `subplot`. The problem of course is that `subplot` sticks in "extra" space. This space is controlled by two factors. The first is the user controlled `SubplotDefaultAxesLocation` property of the application data of figures. The second is a hardcoded `inset` within the `subplot` function. The `SubplotDefaultAxesLocation` property controls the whitespace around the edge of the figure while the `inset` controls the space between the panels. You can remove the space around the figure with

```
hfig = figure;
setappdata(hfig, 'SubplotDefaultAxesLocation', [0, 0, 1, 1])
```

To remove the space between panels you need to edit (or copy edit) `subplot.m` In R2013a the offending lines are 129 and 130

```
% This is the percent offset from the subplot grid of the plotbox.
inset = [.2, .18, .04, .1]; % [left bottom right top]
```

If you change line 130 to be

```
inset = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]; % [left bottom right top]
```

then the panels will not have any space between them. Even better would be something like

```
% This is the percent offset from the subplot grid of the plotbox.
if ~isappdata(ancestorFigure, 'SubplotDefaultInset')
    inset = [.2, .18, .04, .1]; % [left bottom right top]
else
    inset = getappdata(ancestorFigure, 'SubplotDefaultInset');
end
```

so you can control the `inset`. With this slightly modified `subplot` function

```
I = imread('coins.png');
I = imresize(I,[128 128]);

voffset = 0.3;
hfig = figure;
setappdata(hfig, 'SubplotDefaultAxesLocation', [0, voffset/2, 1, 1-voffset]);
setappdata(hfig, 'SubplotDefaultInset', [0, 0, 0, 0]);

nrow = 2;
ncol = 5;
hax = nan(nrow, ncol);
for irow = 1:nrow
    for icol = 1:ncol
        hax(irow, icol) = mysubplot(nrow, ncol, icol+(irow-1)*ncol, 'align');
        imshow(I);
        if irow == 1
            title(hax(irow, icol), ['Curve #', num2str(icol)], 'FontSize',12);
        end
        if irow == nrow
            xlabel(hax(irow, icol), ['(', char(96+icol), ')'], 'FontSize',12);
        end
    end
end
set(hax,  'XTick', [], 'YTick', []);

pos = get(hfig, 'Position');
set(hfig, 'Position', [pos(1:2), (1-voffset)*pos(3), nrow/ncol*pos(3)]);
```

You need the `voffset` to allow the title and xlabel to fit on the figure. You need to scale the figure so that it has the correct aspect ratio to handle the panels. The result is

[image]

The small gap between curve 1 and 2 and curve 3 and 4 appears to be a rendering artefact.

If you want the labels between the rows, you need to add some extra space. For example to add just labels on the x axis you can do

```
voffset = 0.35;
setappdata(hfig, 'SubplotDefaultAxesLocation', [0, voffset/4, 1, 1-voffset/2]);
setappdata(hfig, 'SubplotDefaultInset', [0, voffset/2, 0, 0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but what should I do if I want xlabels to appear for the images of the top row ?

Comment: Thanks again. I will check and let you know!

Answer (score 2):

The `subaxis` funcion you can find here at the [Matlab File Exchange: subaxis](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3696-subaxis-subplot) by Aslak Grinsted offers you a very convenient solution.

Comment: Thanks but i didn't want to use someone else's work. Can you please tell me what is wrong with my code ?

Comment: I can understand that, but as you see it needs quite some effort to get into subplot function. I'm sorry I would have to do a lot of research as well.

Comment: Please check my answer below. It seems to work well. But can it be done in a loop?

Comment: of course, you just have to put all the positions in one matrix, every iteration you go to the next row. The other parameters are iterable as well. The labels with letters are a bit tricky. You have to store the letters in a char-vector and also address by the iteration variable.

Comment: This seems like a good approach. Thanks I will try it out. But can it be done much more faster without using any loops ?

Comment: I doubt it. I mean every single subplot needs be plotted, that can not be done by vectorized solution. But as all images of one row in your solution are linked together, you could combine them before plotting. Needs effort for the labels again then. I would just keep it as it is. Use codefolding of cellsections to hide all that stuff and it won't bother you anymore.

Answer (score 2):

when subplots overlap, the earlier one is hidden.

try slightly decreasing the 'Position' width.

they should show up again

also, there could be some "snap to grid" issues, 
how does this behave when you resize the window?

Comment: My thought was at first that the subplot was overlapping. Anyway it seems I have fixed it. Please check my edited post. 

And By the way when I resize the window , it remains same.

Comment: Please check my answer below. It works well. But can it be done in a loop ?

Answer (score 1):

```
close all
figure,set(gca,'Color','none')
subplot('Position',[0.025 0.51  0.19 0.48]);get(gca,'position');set(gca, 'XTick', []);set(gca, 'YTick', []);
imshow(I);hold on; axis off;
contour((BW(:,:,1)), [0 0], 'r','LineWidth',2);
hold off;title('1st curve','FontSize',12);h=xlabel('(a)','FontSize',12);
s=get(h,'Position');
s(2)=s(2)-28;
set(h,'Position',s);
subplot('Position',[0.025+0.19*1 0.51  0.19 0.48]);get(gca,'position');set(gca, 'XTick', []);set(gca, 'YTick', []);
imshow(I);hold on; axis off;
contour((BW(:,:,2)), [0 0], 'r','LineWidth',2);
hold off;title('2nd curve','FontSize',12);h=xlabel('(b)','FontSize',12);
s=get(h,'Position');
s(2)=s(2)-28;
set(h,'Position',s);
subplot('Position',[0.025+0.19*2 0.51  0.19 0.48]);get(gca,'position');set(gca, 'XTick', []);set(gca, 'YTick', []);
imshow(I);hold on; axis off;
contour((BW(:,:,3)), [0 0], 'r','LineWidth',2);
hold off;title('3rd curve','FontSize',12);h=xlabel('(c)','FontSize',12);
s=get(h,'Position');
s(2)=s(2)-28;
set(h,'Position',s);
subplot('Position',[0.025+0.19*3 0.51  0.19 0.48]);get(gca,'position');set(gca, 'XTick', []);set(gca, 'YTick', []);
imshow(I);hold on; axis off;
contour((BW(:,:,4)), [0 0], 'r','LineWidth',2);
hold off;title('4th curve','FontSize',12);h=xlabel('(d)','FontSize',12);
s=get(h,'Position');
s(2)=s(2)-28;
set(h,'Position',s);
subplot('Position',[0.025+0.19*4 0.51  0.19 0.48]);get(gca,'position');set(gca, 'XTick', []);set(gca, 'YTick', []);
imshow(I);hold on; axis off;
contour((BW(:,:,5)), [0 0], 'r','LineWidth',2);
hold off;title('5th curve','FontSize',12);h=xlabel('(e)','FontSize',12);
s=get(h,'Position');
s(2)=s(2)-28;
set(h,'Position',s);

subplot('Position',[0.025 0.03  0.19 0.48]);get(gca,'position');set(gca, 'XTick', []);set(gca, 'YTick', []);
seg = phi0(:,:,1)<=0;imshow(seg);
h=xlabel('(f)','FontSize',12);
s=get(h,'Position');
s(2)=s(2)-28;
set(h,'Position',s);
subplot('Position',[0.025+0.19*1 0.03  0.19 0.48]);get(gca,'position');set(gca, 'XTick', []);set(gca, 'YTick', []);
seg = phi0(:,:,2)<=0;imshow(seg);
h=xlabel('(g)','FontSize',12);
s=get(h,'Position');
s(2)=s(2)-28;
set(h,'Position',s);
subplot('Position',[0.025+0.19*2 0.03  0.19 0.48]);get(gca,'position');set(gca, 'XTick', []);set(gca, 'YTick', []);
seg = phi0(:,:,3)<=0;imshow(seg);
h=xlabel('(h)','FontSize',12);
s=get(h,'Position');
s(2)=s(2)-28;
set(h,'Position',s);
subplot('Position',[0.025+0.19*3 0.03  0.19 0.48]);get(gca,'position');set(gca, 'XTick', []);set(gca, 'YTick', []);
seg = phi0(:,:,4)<=0;imshow(seg);
h=xlabel('(i)','FontSize',12);
s=get(h,'Position');
s(2)=s(2)-28;
set(h,'Position',s);
subplot('Position',[0.025+0.19*4 0.03  0.19 0.48]);get(gca,'position');set(gca, 'XTick', []);set(gca, 'YTick', []);
seg = phi0(:,:,5)<=0;imshow(seg);
h=xlabel('(j)','FontSize',12);
s=get(h,'Position');
s(2)=s(2)-28;
set(h,'Position',s);
```

Thanks everybody I got the correct answer. I changed my code a bit.

This was the answer I got :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Of course it can be done with a single loop
(using a cell array for your variables, and one for the plotting functions ) 
but for simplicity
i would just lump it as two loops .

```
labels = {'(a)' , '(n)' , '(etc)' , 'asdf','asddf'}
jay=1
for aye =1:5
     subplot('Position',[0.025+0.19*(aye-1) 0.51-0.48*(jay-1)  0.19 0.48]);
    ...
     h=xlabel(labelsabc{aye},'FontSize',12);
     ....
end
```

Comment: I have a query. The first parameter of the 'Position' seems to be working fine but why is the second parameter changing on each iteration ? It may be so that I did not get your answer fully. Can you elaborate your answer please?

Comment: jay is fixed . 
it is 1 for one row and 2 for the other .

but because you also change the data source and the plotting function it is more readable to split it


    contour((BW(:,:,aye))  vs seg = phi0(:,:,aye)